# Svg scale() is not working on Edge(Not Edge Chronium)

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, microsoft-edge

I have code that uses the `scale()` command.

> This works great for chrome and mozilla.
>
> This does not work for edge, i have provided some code so you can easily reproduce the problem.

I am trying to do it manually.
I am already feeling the pain with the amount of calculations that need to be done.

**Is there a better way?**

I am only reversing the x and y.

```
scale(1,-1)
scale(-1,-1)
scale(1,1)
scale(-1,1)
```

Are there any tips in order to achieve this functionality?

> The end result should work for edge.

#### Reproducible Example:

In the svg property try changing `scale(-1, -1)` -> `scale(1,1)`. **Chrome will reverse the axis** while edge will do nothing.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.12.0/d3.js" integrity="sha256-3BMRAc+yX0neFRvyfGGfd3aZK8NKwYTOzq93ubNY2iU=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="example" style="width:1000px;">

    </div>    
</body>
<script>
    const svg = d3.select('#example')
                  .append('svg')
                  .attr('width', '100%')
                  .attr('height', '500%')
                  .attr('transform', 'scale(-1,-1)');

    svg.append('rect')
        .attr('id', 'example-1')
        .attr('width', '20%')
        .attr('height', '30%')
        .attr('x', '10%')
        .attr('y', '20%')
        .attr('fill','red');

    svg.append('rect')
        .attr('id', 'example-1')
        .attr('width', '20%')
        .attr('height', '30%')
        .attr('x', '30%')
        .attr('y', '20%')
        .attr('fill','blue');
    svg.append('rect')
        .attr('id', 'example-1')
        .attr('width', '20%')
        .attr('height', '30%')
        .attr('x', '10%')
        .attr('y', '40%')
        .attr('fill','yellow');
    svg.append('rect')
        .attr('id', 'example-1')
        .attr('width', '20%')
        .attr('height', '30%')
        .attr('x', '30%')
        .attr('y', '40%')
        .attr('fill','orange');

</script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a `<g>` child element and scale that instead.

I've added a translate so you can still see the output in the example and I've made all the id values unique.

```js
const svg = d3.select('#example')
                  .append('svg')
                  .attr('width', '100%')
                  .attr('height', '500%')

    const g = svg.append('g')
        .attr('transform', ' translate(500, 100) scale(-1,-1)');
    g.append('rect')
        .attr('id', 'example-1')
        .attr('width', '20%')
        .attr('height', '30%')
        .attr('x', '10%')
        .attr('y', '20%')
        .attr('fill','red');

    g.append('rect')
        .attr('id', 'example-2')
        .attr('width', '20%')
        .attr('height', '30%')
        .attr('x', '30%')
        .attr('y', '20%')
        .attr('fill','blue');
    g.append('rect')
        .attr('id', 'example-3')
        .attr('width', '20%')
        .attr('height', '30%')
        .attr('x', '10%')
        .attr('y', '40%')
        .attr('fill','yellow');
    g.append('rect')
        .attr('id', 'example-4')
        .attr('width', '20%')
        .attr('height', '30%')
        .attr('x', '30%')
        .attr('y', '40%')
        .attr('fill','orange');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<div id="example" style="width:1000px;"></div>
```

Comment: In edge the SVG root element is not transformable, in other browsers it is. See the second paragraph of my answer for why I added the transform.

Comment: You said you added the translate so i can see the output. I just want to know the role that the transform played. I see similar misbehaviors to my code which i would like to resolve.

Comment: translate moves things, scale scales them. If you flip something about the origin anything to the right of the origin will end up on the left and anything below the origin will end up above.

Comment: It is important to also note that when this happens on the root element, the translate should be removed.